# How can I access a specific value in the output

Tags: python, regex, list, python-re

```py
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    m = re.search(r"core-\b(\d+)", new[i])
    if (m):
        m_1 = (m.group(1))
        #print(m_1)
```

I get the following output from each loop [ 01 01 02 02] after four iterations how can I output just the second 01

Comment: You can just toss a `break` after setting `m_1` to exit the for loop. There may be a more elegant way though since you are using regex, but `break` is quick and works.

Comment: What if I want the second iteration of 01

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I would suggest, then defining `m_1` as a list and adding like `m_1.append(m.group(1))` Then you can access any element of that list outside of your for loop.

Comment: Why is there a loop if you only want the results for one of the iterations? Why not just `re.search(r"core-\b(\d+)", new[1])`?